# When to use “quel” or “quoi”?

Tags: pronoms, interrogative

`Quel` and `quoi` both translate to `what`.

Is there any rule that tells which one should be used?

Comment: Really? I always worked under the assumption that *quel* translated to *which*...

Comment: You will notice that _Quel_ is always followed by a noun, whereas _Quoi_ is never.

Comment: @Rerito Not in the interrogative form: "Quel est ton nom ?"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### 1. Quoi = what (indirect object)

**Don't** use *quoi* in **written** French **without a preposition**, as *quoi* stands for indirect objects -- except in fixed expressions like *quoi qu'il en soit* (nevertheless).

*Quoi* **only** appears **in questions** as the second word, directly after the preposition. Typical prepositions are *de*, *à*, *sur*, *sous*, *en*, *pour* (in this case, both words are written together in *pourquoi*). For example: *de quoi parles-tu ?* (what are you talking **about**?); *à quoi fais-tu allusion?* (what are you referring **to**?)

*Quoi* is used in the **colloquial** mainly spoken French as a substitute for *que* in non-inverted questions: *tu fais quoi ?* standing for *que fais-tu ?* (what are you doing?)

### 2. Quel

*Quel* exists in two forms: as a pronoun and as an adjective:

#### *Quel* as a pronoun = what (direct object)

*Quel* as a pronoun is variable, depending on the object is refers to, and is often subject of a question: *quel est ce film ?*; *quelle est cette plante ?*; *quels sont ces pays ?*; *quelles sont ces couleurs ?*

#### *Quel* as an adjective = which

*Quel* as an adjective is variable, depending on the noun following it; *Quelle heure est-il ?*; *Quel film aimes-tu ?*; *Quels pays as-tu visités ?*; *Quelles couleurs préfères-tu ?*

### 3. Qu'elle = that she

Don't mix up *quelle* and *qu'elle*. *Qu'elle* stands for *que elle* which means *that she* as in *l'homme qu'elle aime* (litt. *the man that she loves*)

Comment: "Quoi" is not "misused" in spoken French and "tu fais quoi ?" is not "grammatically incorrect". The fact that formal written French and colloquial spoken French use different structures doesn't mean that the latter is incorrect. From a linguistic point of view, claiming that "tu fais quoi ?" (a structure used by essentially every native French speaker) is incorrect is absurd.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Quelle** heure est-il ? -> **What** time is it?

**Quel** est celui que tu préfères ? -> **Which** one do you prefer?

Tu fais **quoi** ? *(fam.)* -> **What** are you doing?

**Quel** ou **quoi** peuvent être utilisés dans de nombreux contextes, et avec des déclinaisons :

**Lequel** ? **Que** fais-tu ?

**Quel** est utilisé pour désigner une chose, tandis-que **quoi** est plus abstrait.

**Quel** chien préfères-tu ? **Quoi** de mieux qu'une journée de pêche ?

Answer (score -2):

"Quel" translated to "which" rather than "what".

Comment: C'est un peu plus compliqué que ça.